# In angular slickgrid, the records with special characters "<" , "=" are not getting filtered

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-slickgrid

Im using Angular Slickgrid to display the data and to filter the data ,in that I have noticed that the column filters are not filtering the records with special characters like "<","=".

**Current Behavior:**

Column filters are not filtering the records with special characters like "<","=".

([demo for not filtering records.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjTVt.gif))

**Expected Behavior:**

Column filter needs to filter the records with special characters like ("<","=").

**Software Version**

- Angular : 13.3.9
- Angular-Slickgrid : 4.3.1
- TypeScript : 4.6.4
- Operating System : Windows 10
- Node : 14.18.3
- NPM : 6.14.8

Comment: added a new flag in latest versions, you would need to upgrade in your case, see the updated answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design, they are reserved characters in Angular-Slickgrid Filters and they are interpreted and turned into Filter Operators, from a Regular Expression, when input as the first 1-2 characters. Even if you use the Compound Filters, they will still be interpreted as Operators and will never be part of the search itself (apart from being an Operator). The characters that are being interpreted when being the first 1-2 chars are: `<`, `>`, `=`, `*` (endsWith) and also note that the `*` symbol will also be interpreted when input as the last character (startsWith).

I could maybe add an option in the future to disable this interpretation (perhaps on the Compound Filters) but at this point it's always ON and will never part of the search itself (unless it's in the middle of the search when it's more than 2 characters, basically if you search for `=  =` then it might work)

EDIT

A new option `autoParseInputFilterOperator` was added in this [PR](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/pull/873) to support a way to disable the parsing. This new flag is now available starting with Angular-Slickgrid version [v5.3.0](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/releases/tag/v5.3.0) and Slickgrid-Universal [v2.3.0](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/releases/tag/v2.3.0)